# How can I make a url with speciphic javascript function to run when the page is load

Tags: javascript, function, url

I was wondering if i can to make url such like this:

```
http://www.google.com/index.php?id=mycustomsearch,javascript:onload=initfunction1();
```

To make myself clear i'll explain.
I want to modify the link to make a javascript action.
To be able to give the same exact page but triger every time another function based on the link.

I wrote [,] just for demonstration. I dunno if there is a way to do it.

Comment: Sounds like an XSS attackers dream....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay do not approach the problem via a query string in the URL.  This is will open your site up to XSS attacks.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

If you wanted to run a JavaScript function once the page has loaded use `JavaScript` or `jQuery` and do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   YourFunction();
 });

function YourFunction() {
   alert('Your function logic');
}
```

You could filter the function name via the query string, sure, however do not embed JavaScript into the URL.

```
http://www.yoursite.com/?function=YourFunction
```

Comment: yeah. i know to do that.
what im trying to do is not the XSS thing, its just to change styling in the page. like:
"http://mypage.com/index.html,javascript:$("#tooltip").style.color='blue';"

Comment: @user1648920 yes I understand but thats not the correct way to do custom styling - using javascript via the URL will leave your site vulnerable to attackers.  For the styling problem you mention, the user preferences should be stored in either a database or at the client level, i.e. a cookie.  Your site will then base the style upon these preferences.

Comment: thank you. i'll use cookies, can you guide me to a place where i can learn how to use cookies please?
thankes in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Without using something like greasemonkey installed on your machine, no, you can't (and shouldn't) do this. If the URL is on one of your domains, you can embed the script in your page, if it's someone else's... no.

Comment: look, if write now you go to adress bar and write:
"javascript:alert('i\'m happy')" it will work even if it not your domain, so basically i want to do that in my site, give custumers diffrent links based on their origin. but they all go to same page.

Comment: You can't do that to someone else's domain. It's fundamentally not how browsers work.